# Is the glass held by the old female patient invisible on purpose?

Tags: shutter-island

In the scene in *Shutter Island* where Dicaprio's character interrogates an old patient, she asks for water. After a while, Chuck gets her a glass of water, which is nowhere to be seen as she drinks from it.

Am I blind? Or isn't there a real glass? And if so, it's too hard to be an error. It must have been done on purpose. So what does it mean?

[image]
[image]